# What does the VirtualProtectEx function actually do ? (WINAPI)

Tags: c++, assembly, winapi, memory

This is a function that is supposed to patch bytes at a specific place in memory (in a specific process).

What does the VirtualProtectEx function actually do and why is it required to patch the bytes ?

```
void PatchEx(BYTE* dst, BYTE* src, unsigned int size, HANDLE hProcess)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dst, src, size, nullptr);
    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}
```

I tried to look it up on msdn but I dont really understand their description.

I dont understand why is it required. Because I think I already have rights to write to memory ? Why do i need to give it extra rights and what is the point of the `DWORD oldprotect;` ?

Comment: VirtualProtectEx is not needed here because WriteProcessMemory takes care of that for you. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181206-00/?p=100415

Comment: I would comment that ignoring return values and not checking for errors is a very bad idea. You should research how to do that correctly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where can i research that ? Could you tell me a source ? And why am I ignoring return values ? You mean the returns of VirtualProtectEx ?

Comment: `a = func(b)`, this captures the return value; `func(b)` this ignores it. Any good guide to Win32 programming will show you how to handle return values with a view to error checking. You make three Win32 API calls in the code above, and ignore the return value in all of them?

Comment: Internals: It changes the Paging Protection of the page. Check my [assembly manual](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1273844/The-Intel-Assembly-Manual) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as the docs say, `VirtualProtectEx` changes the memory protection settings for a memory range, in the process specified. (As opposed to `VirtualProtect`, which always works on the current process.)

In this particular case, the first call to the function ensures that the memory you're about to write is actually writable, while storing the old protection settings in `oldprotect`. The second call resets the settings back to what they were; this is just being a good citizen.

> Because I think I already have rights to write to memory ?

You may have access rights to the process in question (and if not, the function will fail, but you actually don't check for that). But by default, code in a process is not writable. You have the rights to change that if the process is running at the same privilege level and in the same session as your hack. But you need to do it.

Also, you obviously didn't write this function yourself, so while in your particular case the memory even might be writable, the original author can't assume this.

Comment: "But you need to do it". Actually you don't. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181206-00/?p=100415

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you should still do it

Comment: @RaymondChen Is that because `WriteProcessMemory` doesn't guarantee that it will happen? Or is it because if `VirtualProtectEx` fails you can give more granular error messages?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It might be because this behavior is actually *contrary to the documentation*: "Before data transfer occurs, the system verifies that all data in the base address and memory of the specified size is accessible for write access, and if it is not accessible, the function fails." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory

Comment: It's a courtesy, not contractual behavior. Also, it hides a race condition.